# Testing a trace table in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

Working through trace tables and wanted to check to see if my results where correct, I have designed the following code to check each stage of the loop, but the code keeps throwing up an error about casting when i try to run it. I can see when the error comes back that the writeline is holding info but what have i done wrong.

```
Module Module1


    Sub Main()
        Dim aWord As String
        Dim bWord As String
        Dim result As Boolean
        Dim temp As Char
        Dim pos As Integer
        Dim index As Integer
        index = 0
        aWord = "Simple"
        bWord = "abcdef"
        result = True
        If Not (aWord.Length = bWord.Length) Then
            result = False
        Else
            While index < bWord.Length And result
                temp = bWord.Chars(index)
                pos = aWord.IndexOf(temp)
                If pos >= 0 Then
                    aWord = aWord.Remove(pos, 1)

                Else
                    result = False
                End If

                WriteLine(bWord, aWord, temp, pos.ToString, index.ToString)

            End While

        End If

    End Sub


End Module
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling WriteLine() incorrectly.  It should be:

`WriteLine("{0}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {4}", bWord, aWord, temp, pos.ToString, index.ToString)`

Comment: Getting an error Conversion from string "{0}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {4}" to type 'Integer' is not valid. and what is the reason for the bit you added on i have not seen this as far

Comment: Oh.  I assumed you were talking to Console.WriteLine().  Was I mistaken?

Comment: Sorry thats what im doing makes sense but it is just disappearing off the screen now when i run it how do it stop this